# CodeIgniter - How to call controller and get returned value from within a library

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to call a specific method in a controller that returns a value, from within a library, but all I found so far is redirecting to a route like this :

```
redirect('Controller1/method1')
```

And this is not what I need, I don't want to redirect to a route but get a value from the called method.

Comment: If you want to call from within `controller` you can use `$this->method1()` and if you want to call method from `view` then you should use `ajax`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling controller method from library, may be not a correct approach.

Any how try below 2 solutions

Solution #1

Create CodeIgniter object and try to access the method required

```
$this->CI = & get_instance();
$this->CI->requiredMethod()
```

Solution #2

Try this in least case

```
Include required controller in the library file
include_once 'application/controllers/YourController.php';

Create obj and call
$obj = new YourController();
$obj->requiredMethod()
```